# How to open/display NotebookObject in the front end

Tags: notebooks

After creating a notebook using the following command i get

```
TemplateApply[
    NotebookTemplate[FileNameJoin[{$myPath,"myTemplate.nb"}]],
    data
]
```

[image]

How do i open this notebook object in the front end? I tried `NotebookOpen[%]` but it doesnot work.

Comment: I want to open the `NotebookObject` in general and btw `CreateNotebook[%]` is also not working.

Comment: Does `SetOptions[%, Visible -> True]` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example from the [`NotebookTemplate` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookTemplate.html)

```
TemplateApply[
  NotebookTemplate["ExampleData/BasicTemplate.nb"],
  <|"author" -> "Sarah Miles"|>
 ]
```

> [image: NotebookObject]

returns a `NotebookObject` without opening/displaying it.
The reason for this behavior is that the created notebook is not visible. One can make it visible (/open it) using

```
SetOptions[%, Visible -> True]
```

or

```
CurrentValue[%, Visible] = True
```

---

The template notebook itself doesn't have an explicit `Visible` option setting

```
Options[Import["ExampleData/BasicTemplate.nb"], Visible]
```

> `{}`

but the `NotebookOject` inside the `TemplateObject` created with

```
NotebookTemplate["ExampleData/BasicTemplate.nb"]
```

does:

```
Options[NotebookTemplate["ExampleData/BasicTemplate.nb"][[1]], Visible]
```

> `{Visible -> False}`

---

If the template notebook has the option setting `Visible->True` the generated notebook will be visible right away

```
bt = Append[Import["ExampleData/BasicTemplate.nb"], Visible -> True];
TemplateApply[NotebookTemplate[bt],
 <|"author" -> "Sarah Miles"|>
 ]
```

However, the template notebook itself will also be visible.